# Randomly splitting Feature Collection in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: javascript, classification, google-earth-engine

I am trying to do a supervised classification in Google Earth Engine and created around 50 polygons for each of my 5 categories and put them into Feature Collections and merged them into one single feature collection with the property "class".

Now I want to split this feature collection into two random samples - the first sample I will use for training my classifier, and the second for validating the classification afterwards.

I have been trying different strategies. I e.g. tried reducing it to an image (images are able to be split into random samples according to the GEE tutorials), but I could not manage to keep the property "class" (the only relevant property my feature collection has). I also tried inserting a random column in my feature collection and filtering by it, which did NOT work:

```
//merging feature collections
var fc = water.merge(croplandVEG).merge(croplandBARE).merge(urban).merge(naturalVEG);

var newfc = fc.randomColumn();

print(newfc);

//split the image of the training points into Training & Accuracy samples!

var filterrandom0 = ee.Filter.equals('random',0);
var trainingsample = newfc.filter(filterrandom0);

var filterrandom1 = ee.Filter.equals('random',1);
var accuracysample = newfc.filter(filterrandom1);

// Get the values for all pixels in each polygon in the training.
var training = clipped.sampleRegions({
  // Get the sample from the polygons FeatureCollection.
  collection: trainingsample,
  // Keep this list of properties from the polygons.
  properties: ['class'],
  // Set the scale to get Landsat pixels in the polygons.
  scale: 100
});

// Create a random forest classifier with custom parameters.
var classifier = ee.Classifier.randomForest().train({
  features: training,
  classProperty: 'class',
  inputProperties: bands
});

// Train the classifier.
var trained = classifier.train(training, 'class', bands);

// Classify the image.
var classified = clipped.classify(trained);

// Classify the validation data.
var validated = accuracysample.classify(classifier);
```

For this I get the error code:

> ConfusionMatrix (Error)
>
> No data was found in classifier training
>   input.

Why is this possible for images but not for feature collections on Google Earth Engine? Here is how I tried reducing it to an image, which also did not work so far:

```
var newimage = fc
  .reduceToImage(['class'],
  ee.Reducer.firstNonNull()).select(['first'], ['class']);

  // Sample the input imagery to get a FeatureCollection of training data.
var trainingsample = newimage.stratifiedSample({
  scale: 100,
  numPoints: 5000,
  seed: 0
});

var accuracysample = newimage.stratifiedSample({
  scale: 100,
  numPoints: 5000,
  seed: 1
});
```

To which I get the error code:

> Unable to transform geometry into requested projection.

Answer (score 6):

Okay, I figured it out myself and want to share the answer for anyone else who has the problem.

First, it is possible to split a feature class with the random column. My mistake was however to put "ee.Filter.equals('random',0)", as the random column does not only consist of 0s and 1s, but of ANY number between 0 and 1. So what I instead did was:

```
var filterrandom0 = ee.Filter.greaterThan('random',0.2);
var trainingsample = newfc.filter(filterrandom0);

var filterrandom1 = ee.Filter.lessThan('random',0.2);
var accuracysample = newfc.filter(filterrandom1);
```

I chose 80% of my data as training data and 20% as accuracy data. This gives back a Feature Collection.

However, this still does not work to just use it as an accuracysample. To assess the accuracy, you need to classify the image twice - once with training data, once with accuracydata, and then compare the images. So I forgot to introduce the step that actually transforms this trainingsample into the data I need:

```
// Get the values for all pixels in each polygon in the training.
var training = image.sampleRegions({
  // Get the sample from the polygons FeatureCollection.
  collection: newfc,
  // Keep this list of properties from the polygons.
  properties: ['class'],
  // Set the scale to get Landsat pixels in the polygons.
  scale: 100
});
```

So, it is much smarter to just split this training data that I made directly, which I did with:

```
var withRandom = training.randomColumn('random');

var split = 0.7;  // Roughly 70% training, 30% testing.
var trainingPartition = withRandom.filter(ee.Filter.lt('random', split));
var testingPartition = withRandom.filter(ee.Filter.gte('random', split));

// Trained with 70% of our data.
var trainedClassifier = ee.Classifier.randomForest().train({
  features: trainingPartition,
  classProperty: 'class',
  inputProperties: bands
});

// Classify the test FeatureCollection.
var test = testingPartition.classify(trainedClassifier);

// Print the confusion matrix.
var confusionMatrix = test.errorMatrix('class', 'classification');
print('Confusion Matrix', confusionMatrix);
print('Validation overall accuracy: ', confusionMatrix.accuracy());
```

This should in theory work, however, I always get the error code:

> ConfusionMatrix (Error) Computation timed out.

So, new question:

How do I avoid the time out? What causes the time out and how do I stop it?

The link to the whole script is here:

https://code.earthengine.google.com/c8c2701a804d9f025a73e94d2cad63c6

Comment: A new question is best suited as just that - ask a new question. Otherwise we would need to answer it in comments to this answer.

Comment: Okay, thanks! I figured it out now, the time-out was just a small mistake in my script. The version I posted actually works fine!

Comment: I have followed the same steps for splitting the reference data and did the accuracy assessment.But am getting this same error message: ConfusionMatrix (Error) Computation timed out. Can I know how this was solved?